# Solving Higher-Order Kinetic Energy Term (Gross-Pitaevskii equation)

Tags: non-linear-systems, solitons, non-linear-schroedinger

Consider now propagation of non-linear waves in one-dimensional chain of dimers governed by the non-linear Schrödinger equation for the normalized wave envelope $\Psi(x,t)$, 
$$
i \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}+\frac {1} {2}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}+\alpha\vert{\Psi}\vert^2\Psi=0,  \tag 1
$$
where $t$ is time or propagation variable, $x$ is the spatial coordinate, and $\alpha$ describes the non-linearity or interaction strength. 
 I would like to solve numerically the Gross-Pitaevski Eq. (1).

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking for here.

Comment: @flippiefanus,  to solve with second order derivatives.

Comment: @flippiefanus,  my questions is to solve a modified equation with a higher-order kinetic energy term.

Comment: @DavidH you say an awful lot before you ever get to a question (actually you never ask one!).  why don't you make it more concise?

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird, just to make it clear to flippiefanus

Comment: I still don't see a question...

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird, the Schrodinger equation  with a higher-order kinetic energy term

Comment: That is a statement (a fragment actually!).  What about it?  what do you want to know?  A question ends in a question mark.

Comment: I would like to solve the modified equation (for the case of second order spatial derivatives). Once we replace first order with second order derivatives the equations match  those for spinor BECs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45901/discussion-between-david-h-and-confusinglycuriousthethird).

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird, is it clear now?